# Gradle refer task type from another project

Tags: gradle

Here is the file structure:

```
/some/project/a.gradle
/some/project/common/subproject/b.gradle
```

In file a.gradle, I have:

```
apply plugin: "java"
class ClassThatExtendsDefaultTask extends DefaultTask {
  ...
}
```

In file b.gradle:

```
apply from: "$rootDir/a.gradle"
task someTask(type: ClassThatExtendsDefaultTask) {
  ...
}
compileTestJava.dependsOn someTask
```

However, when I run gralew test, I got:

```
Task with path 'ClassThatExtendsDefaultTask' not found in project ':common:subproject'.
```

So my question is how can I refer a java task in another file? I to copy paste ClassThatExtendsDefaultTask from a.gradle to b.gradle, it actually works.

Comment: where do you run `gradlew` from? Is `$rootDir` pointing at the right place?

Comment: $rootDir point to /some/project/. And I run my gradlew at /some/project/common/subproject/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should consider moving the class to buildSrc. That is, extract the class to file `ClassThatExtendsDefaultTask.groovy` and place it in folder '[rootDir]/buildSrc/src/main/groovy' (where [rootDir] is the root directory of your project).

You should also consider placing it in a package below that directory, but if so you will need to import or fully-qualify the class name.

There are several benefits. It is compiled and available in all sub-projects. You can write test code (buildSrc is itself a groovy project).

See: [gradle buildSrc doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources)